# Translate strings that are displayed within a list

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem, which is that I have a list and this list contains strings.

The strings come from an enum called Stage.

I want these strings to be displayed translated.

But my problem is that numbers are displayed with strings.

How can I solve this problem?

After updating my answer, I saw this error:

you can't convert string to number, that happen because stage sent to backend as number, and It is displayed in the list as a string, but after update, it send to backend as string,

How can i solve the problem?

[image]

```
enum Stage {
  UnAssigned = 0,
  PreAcceptance = 1,
  Accepted = 2,
  BeforeTransplantation = 3,
  DayOfTransplantation = 4,
  AfterTransplantation = 5,
  EndOfTransplantationProcess = 6,
  PeriodicFollowUp = 7,
  TransplantationFailure = 8,
  RecoveryAfterTransplantation = 9,
  Waiting = 10,
  Dead = 11,
}

export default Stage;


const stageOptions = Object.values(Stage)
.filter((key) => typeof key === "number")
.map((key) => ({
  value: Number(key),
  label: intl.formatMessage({ id: `${Stage[key]}` }),
}));

     <Col sm="6">
              <FormComp
                label={<FormattedMessage id="stage" />}
                controlHook={controlHook}
                name="stage"
                type="select"
                options={stageOptions}
                errors={errors}
                disabled={disabled}
                required
              />
            </Col>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TypeScript enums, passing in a string will give you the corresponding number, while passing in a number will give you the corresponding string.
`Stage[10] === 'Waiting'`, and `Stage['Waiting'] === 10`.

The problem is that means that the strings and the numbers are all properties of the enum (run `console.log(Stage)` and you'll see), so `Object.keys()` will give you a list of the strings *and* the numbers.

You can get around this by filtering using `Object.values()` and `filter()`.

```
const stageOptions = Object.values(Stage)
  .filter(key => typeof key === 'number')
  .map((key) => ({
    value: key,
    label: `${Stage[key]}`
  }));
```

This way, your keys will only be the numbers, so your labels will only be the corresponding strings.

Comment: but i get problem, that i can't convert string to int,

Comment: @HibaYoussef Can you explain what you tried? I tried out a small example here: https://codepen.io/SonicBoomNFA/pen/qBLgmwj—the filtered version should correctly give an object where the `value`s are only numbers and `label`s are only strings. Where is this error with converting string to int coming from?

Comment: i update my question, Please check it out

Comment: You're close to fixing it, but things are getting a bit confusing since we're talking about numbers/strings to refer to datatypes _and_ to refer to your enum integers/words. So it might help if you display an image of the exact errors you're seeing (as well as what the dropdown looks like now).